# select box value on select shows in the textfield

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have been trying to make an script in php that allows me when i select any option on the select box then on selecting it its value gets displayed in the textfield. Kindly let me know how can i do that. I am a rookie so kindly bear my question if its stupid.

Kindly clcik on the followi8ng link for image help of my quesiton.

http://s18.postimage.org/d85l2m2nt/select_Box2.gif

Comment: JavaScript is more suited for this task than PHP.

Comment: or try jquery. server-side language can't be a solution in this problem

Comment: @Mahan PHP *can* solve this problem. In fact, before JavaScript existed, you had to solve this problem on the server end.

Comment: using POST/GET request? then put it on a textfield on the next page?

Comment: @Mahan Yup. That is one of the reasons JavaScript was so attractive. You wouldn't have to wait 15 or 20 seconds for a full page refresh. Of course with better internet speeds today, you wouldn't wait that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slectboxid option').click(function(){
      $('#textboxid').val($(this).val());
            });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="select" id="slectboxid">
  <option value="test">test</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="text" id="textboxid" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

use jquery,the above code snippet.it will help you.

Comment: Why are you counting the number of clicks, and why do you start counting at 2?

Answer (score 1):

If your elements are in a form, then put the following listener on the select element:

```
onchange="this.form.textareaName.value = this.value"
```

Where *textareaName* is the name of the textarea you want to set the value of.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function assignText(obj) {
    document.getElementById("textboxid").value = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
   }
</script>  
</head> 
<body> 
    <form action="#" method="post"> 
        <select name="select" id="slectboxid" onchange = 'assignText(this)'> 
            <option value="test">test</option>  
            <option value="test2">test2</option> 
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="textboxid" />
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```